# Issue while trying to plot multiple RSI based MAs with pinescript in Tradingview

Tags: trading, tradingview-api

To the general RSI pinescript available at tradingview.com where i wanted to add some more MAs, I could plot multiple MAs with this version but not getting option to change there  period, please help.

I want to plot 3 to 4 RSI-based MA's, ofcourse I want to be able to decide on the period and how many plots I want at a time.

Couldn't post the code over here as the pf is not allowing me too.